# How can I make the right column take fixed width when left column takes a percentage width?

Tags: html, css, grid

I'm trying to clone Facebook's photo modal/lightbox where it takes the full width of the screen. It has two parts - left part is the photo and the right part is the comments section.

I made the container as well as the responsive part which works perfectly, except one thing. The right column is supposed to have a fixed width but as I used `30%`, it also gets shorter in small screens. But Facebook's comments section always stays in fixed width without horizontal scroll but the left column responses to screen sizes. My one's left column responses perfectly to screen sizes but the right one gets shorter. I want to keep it fixed and without having a horizontal scroll.

There's probably a way of doing it by using CSS's `calc` function.

Pleae note that I am using CSS's grid system and `grid-template-columns` to make the columns.

```css
body{
    background-color: red;
    margin:0;
    padding:0;
    box-sizing: border-box;
}

.container {
    width: 100%;
    height: 100vh;
    background-color: green;
    display: inline-grid;
    grid-template-columns: 70% 30%;  
}

.container__image {
    background-color: blue;
    display: flex;
    justify-content: center;
    flex-direction: column;
    align-items: center;
}

.container__image img {
    max-width: 100%;
    max-height: 100vh;
}


.container__comments {
    background-color: darkgray;
}


@media ( max-width: 900px) {
    .container {
        grid-template-columns: 100%;  
    }
}
```

```html
<div class="container">
      <div class="container__image" >
             <img src="https://wallpapercave.com/wp/aUdwg3C.jpg" />
      </div>

      <div class="container__comments" >comments</div>

</div>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Add `grid-template-columns: 1fr 300px` for `.container`:

```
.container {
    width: 100%;
    height: 100vh;
    background-color: green;
    display: inline-grid;

    grid-template-columns: 1fr 300px;
}
```

The right panel will always be a fixed width.

Comment: Oh man, it's perfect. Can you please explain what you did there?

Comment: @Zak, Yes :) I just changed the parameters in one of the rules of rule `grid-template-columns`. Your left side with the picture is equal to 1 fraction, and the right side is 300 pixels. In this case, your block "comments" will not shrink.